# oAuth Tutorial need in PHP for Twitter & Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, oauth

I have question that is their any good and easy tutorial to do oAth for Twitter and Facebook ... i want to make an application i want to perform many actions but in the beginning i am stuck how to do that .. i google it but not any reliable source i found or i am not getting any easy solution is their any good tutorial how to implement oAth for twitter and Facebook ... i am new in php please let me know... I am very thankful if some one give me appropriate details which i want thanking in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reading the facebook developer guide it's got code samples and everything, can't speak for twitter but I imagine they are pretty well documented. https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: There is also a library available here http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html, I've used it myself and it's really pretty nifty, has examples for facebook, twitter, google, yahoo and more

Comment: @Dale ohh thats great ... phpclassess is awesome .. thanks soo much... i will look into it .. can you tell me is easy to use..

Comment: Yes it's pretty straight forward and has great examples that come with it

Comment: I just downloaded it, and am working through oauth-api. The very first line is an include of http.php, but that's not in the library. Can someone point to a Q&A or forum for this library?

Comment: @GregoryLewis the HTTP class is available from the same site http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3-PHP-HTTP-client-to-access-Web-site-pages.html and appears as dependency when you download the PHP OAuth API package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

oAuth isn't realy easy to understand quickly.

[Maybe this is a helpfull tutorial for Twitter](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/).

[And one for facebook.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/?search_index=3)

I love Tuts+

Comment: thanks for the great tutorials... love this .. awesome